# Cant Access Window.location.replace after IF ELSE in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

I try to replace my page , but it cant still replace.
i think that error from after IF and ELSE after i loged from console
but still cant resolve that.
help..

```
function LoginWithEmail(){

var email = curEmail.indexOf(emailLogin.value);

var password = curPass.indexOf(passLogin.value);

if(emailLogin.value === curEmail[email] && passLogin.value === curPass[password]){
  return window.location.replace("admin-dashboard.php");  
}else{
  alert("Your email or password are empty or wrong!");
  return false;
}

}
```

Comment: do you get the alert instead?

Comment: Remove the "===" in your if statement and make the "==" and it should work.

Comment: why would that be, @SteveB?

Comment: @SteveB , from first code , i use that one, and doesnt work

Comment: @JaromandaX , yes i do , but mechine cant read my window.location.replace i try from console,log and alert are working

Comment: @JaromandaX, === is strict equality and I made an assumption that the issue was the types were not the same even though it's technically a string comparison. I could be wrong

Comment: Have you put a console.log in the if statement to ensure it is running. Are you getting an error outputted to console you can share?

Comment: @SteveB , evidently , the issues come from Retrun true statement guys, while it return false , it can be read , but return true cant

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and then edit your question to conform with the site guidelines. Off-topic questions such as this one are routinely closed, but if edited to ask an *answerable* question, can be re-opened again. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you return `window.location.replace`? According to documentation, this method has no return value.